# Netbeans IDE - actionPerformed()

Tags: java, netbeans

I’m a netbeans user. I have a problem with the netbeans IDE and this seems like a bug. When I’m trying to add an actionPerformed method to a button, automatically it creates an actionPerformed method within another button’s actionPerformed method. This situation causes lot of errors.

How to handle this?

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
      //expressions
      //expressions
      //expressions 
      //expressions
      //expressions


private void btnValiedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
}

    //expressions
    //expressions
    //expressions 
    //expressions 
    //expressions 

}
}
```

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using?